# Group items in a listbox based on user multiselect

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm looking for ideas on how to best accomplish the following. I have a simple listbox of ObservableCollection. I allow the user to select multiple items. I want to let them "group" their selection. E.G. They select 3 items and click "group" and these 3 become associated with one another.
This listbox represents columns in data tables. When they group items they are saying they want these columns concatenated into one return. Based on this I don't really care how this is done as long as when they finally hit submit I can run through the list and see which ones they want stuck together.
So, I guess I'm technically not "grouping" but "tagging". I know there are other challenges relating to how to interpret tagged items but I'll work on that later.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Add another table with three columns. Tag ( or Alias maybe ), ColumnName and order. Then write some intermediate processing code.

Depending on how dynamic your data this could return an expando, a dynamically generated type or a type you define using generated code ( emit ).  That takes the data from columns, appends it by the order specified, sets the property based on columname  and returns the new object. This will likely be inefficient unless you emit that as well.

Comment: My use of "3" was arbitrary. They could select any number to concatenate. I'm now thinking I just need to capture what's selected each time they hit the "group" button. If I store those items in their own list I can then figure out later which ones belong together. This probably isn't as hard as I thought it was. I'll leave the question up for a few days because I'll probably learn something from the responses.

Comment: So long as you pick more than one then you need to know the order they will be concatenated in. Unless you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this. I ended up just taking whatever was selected in the list when the user clicked "combine" and i assigned them to their own group list. They all got a common GUID of sorts and stored in the DB.